# No reconoce bootstrap en snappypdf laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, composer

Estoy usando Laravel Snappy para generar archivo PDF; pero al momento de generarlo no me reconoce los estilos de bootstrap y lo he configurado de la siguiente forma y me acabo de percatar que esta dando error cuando ejecuto npm run build para compilar los cambios.

Este es el erro que me sale en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui les muestro la configuracion de los archivos:

1. Vite.config.js

```
import laravel, { refreshPaths } from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    laravel({
      input: [
        //'resources/css/app.css',
        'resources/js/app.js',
      ],
      refresh: [
        ...refreshPaths,
        'app/Http/Livewire/**',
      ],
    }),
  ],
});
```

2. app.js

```
import '../sass/app.scss';
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
import focus from '@alpinejs/focus';
window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.plugin(focus);

Alpine.start();
```

3. app.scss

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Variables
@import 'variables';

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

// Custom
@import "custom";
```

Por ultimo asi queda mi PDF sin estilos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme, no logro dar con la solucion, estoy usando laravel 9.

Gracias

Comment: probá definiendo el alias `resolve: { alias: { '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'),}},` en `vite.config.js` ( o cambiando el path en el scss )

Comment: Aplique el cambio pero no reconoce y lo malo esque me sale ese erro cuando quiero hacer la compilacion con npm run build

Comment: el error es q no encuentra el stylesheet de bootstrap, si está instalado via npm debería quedar en la carpeta `./node_modules/bootstrap` de la cual `~bootstrap/` por lo general es un alias. fijate si existe la carpeta o si hace falta un `npm install`, `npm run build` por lo general ejecuta los scripts definidos en la seccion `scripts` de `package.json`

Comment: Revise el archivo package.json y si esta la dependencia "bootstrap": "^5.1.0"; tambien revise ./node_modules/bootstrap y esta la carpeta bootstrap aun sigue detectando el problema con // Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap'; en el app.scss :c

Comment: Laravel-snappy usa wkhtmltopdf, y según tengo entendido no se lleva nada bien con bootstrap 4 o 5 teniendo en cuenta el uso de Flex. Tuve un problema similar y mi solución fue usar bootstrap3 solo para la plantilla PDF. La otra opción crea tus propios estilos.

Comment: fijate que el nombre del archivo de config este todo en minusculas `mv Vite.config.js vite.config.js` .  puede q `vite build` no esté [encontrando su config](https://vitejs.dev/config/#configuring-vite) ( no setea alias no encuentra bootstrap falla el chain build )